# It is not supported to create click packages for a non UbuntuSDK target

Tags: application-development, ubuntu-sdk, qml, click-packages

I've just finished a first version of my app port to QML and tried to create a click package but Ubuntu SDK said

> Wrong kit type
>   It is not supported to create click packages for a non UbuntuSDK target

My project is of type `QML Extension Library + Tabbed UI` and I've removed `networking` from policies. How can I create the package?

```
click build .
```

doesn't really work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Get at least 1 GiB free disk space

   ```
   sudo apt-get install schroot
   ```
2. Tools > Options > Ubuntu > Create Click Target > armhf (i386 and amd64 targets are broken as of now)
3. Projects > Add Kit > UbuntuSDK
4. Select it and build against it.
5. Publish.

#### Optional

1. Create an emulator image.
2. Install gdb-multiarch:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install gdb-multiarch
   ```